# How to separate numbers from String

Tags: java

I have to do the following using only for loops and if statements, String and Character methods (no String Builder):

"Write a method called printGPA that accepts a Scanner for the console as
a parameter and calculates a student's grade point average.  The user will
type a line of input containing the students name, then a number that 
represents the number of scores, followed by that many integer scores."

The example given is :

Enter a student record: Maria 5 72 91 84 89 78

Maria's grade is 82.8

I have successfully done this with the below code:

```
public class Exercise8 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        printGPA(consoleInput);     
    }
    public static void printGPA(Scanner input)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a student record: ");
        String name = input.next();
        int total = input.nextInt();
        String grades = input.nextLine();

        int sum = 0;        
        String stringConcat = "";
        double gpa = 0.0;

        System.out.println("Student record: " + name + " " + total + " " +
            grades);

        for(int i = 1; i < grades.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = grades.charAt(i);
            char ch2 = grades.charAt(i + 1);                
            stringConcat = String.valueOf(ch) + String.valueOf(ch2);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(stringConcat);
            sum += number;
            gpa = (double)sum / (double)total;              
            i += 2;         
        }   
    System.out.println(name + "'s grade is " + gpa);
 }
```

}

The program works great as long as I don't throw a 100 or a 0 into the equation.  I cannot figure out how to create an algorithm that will strop the 100's or 0's from the String regardless of where they are located within the string.

Edit:

For example: If I input 72, 100, 98, 0, 87 I need to separate them from the string and turn them into integers so that I can add them.

If I input the above I receive the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 9"

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Chapter4.Exercise8.printGPA(Exercise8.java:37)
at Chapter4.Exercise8.main(Exercise8.java:16)
```

Comment: Your code is more or less unrelated to your actual problem. Give examples of your input and your desired string.

Comment: Try and include some details about what exactly happens when you have a 100 or a 0 in the input. Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say? Which line of code does it point to? What is the message trying to tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Scanner.nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) instead of manually parsing the String. This will handle variable length integers instead of where your code only handles two digit numbers. That is why it fails on 0-9 and 100.

```
for( int i = 0; i < total; i++ ) {
    gpa += scanner.nextInt();
}
gpa = gpa / total;
```

Edit: You may also want to add error handling to detect if a grade is below 0 or higher than 100, since those don't make sense in this context.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I wasn't aware that you could do that.  That made everything a thousand times easier.

Answer (score 1):

You're only getting 2 characters at a time from the string. 1 and 3 character numbers break the code. Do this:

```
String[] grades = input.nextLine().split(" ");
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
{
    int number = Integer.parseInt(grades[i]);
    sum += number;
    gpa = (double)sum / (double)total;              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same textbook and this is how I did the exercise, which implements the technique mentioned by Smith_61. [This is my first post so tell me if it's helpful and works formatted properly, the 4 space thing confused me for a while].

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class C4E8
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        printGPA(console);
    }
    public static void printGPA(Scanner input)
    {
        int total = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter a student record? ");
        String name = input.next();
        int n = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            total += input.nextInt();
        }
        double gpa = (double) total / n;
        System.out.println(name + "'s grade is " + gpa);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can do the following. After,  `String grades = input.nextLine();`

```
Scanner gradeScanner = new Scanner(grades);

int sum = 0;

int numOfGrades = 0;

while(gradeScanner.hasNextInt()){
    sum += gradeScanner.nextInt();
    numOfGrades++;
}

double avg = sum / numOfGrades;
```

Of course you have to remove the way you are reading the numbers

**NOTE:** I am assuming you input grades like this `12 20 15 16` etc.. I.e use `" "` as delimiter.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using the String `grades`. You should use a loop of `nextInt()` until there are no more grades. For example:

```
System.out.print("Enter a student record: ");
String name = input.next();
int totalGrades = 0;
int total = input.nextInt();
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    totalGrades += input.nextInt();
}
double gpa = totalGrades/total;

System.out.println("Student record: " + name + " " + total + " " +
        grades);
System.out.println(name + "'s grade is " + gpa);
```

This assumes the input is always `Name NumOfGrades Grade Grade Grade // etc. for as many grades as needed`

You grab the name with the scanner, than create a cumulative value of all the grades while counting how many grades are. Then, with simple division, you find the GPA. You can print out the same exact way as you did before.